# Localization in Perl using gettext and Locale::TextDomain, with fallback if Locale::TextDomain is not available

Tags: perl, localization, internationalization, gettext

The "[On the state of i18n in Perl](http://rassie.org/archives/247)" blog post from 26 April 2009 recommends using [Locale::TextDomain](http://p3rl.org/Locale::TextDomain) module from libintl-perl distribution for l10n / i18n in Perl.  Besides I have to use gettext anyway, and gettext support in Locale::Messages / Locale::TextDomain is more natural than in gettext emulation in [Locale::Maketext](http://p3rl.org/Locale::Maketext).

The subsection "[15.5.18 Perl](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Perl)" in chapter "[15 Other Programming Languages](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Programming-Languages)" in GNU gettext manual says:

> **Portability**
>
> The `libintl-perl` package is platform independent but is not part of the Perl core. The programmer is responsible for providing a dummy implementation of the required functions if the package is not installed on the target system.

However neither of two examples in [`examples/hello-perl`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gettext.git/tree/gettext-tools/examples/hello-perl/) in gettext sources (one using lower level Locale::Messages, one using higher level Locale::TextDomain) includes **detecting** if the package is installed on the target system, and providing **dummy implementation** if it is not.

What is complicating matter (with respect to detecting if package is installed or not) is the following fragment of Locale::TextDomain manpage:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> use Locale::TextDomain ('my-package', @locale_dirs);
>
> use Locale::TextDomain qw (my-package);
> ```
>
> **USAGE**
>
> It is crucial to remember that you use Locale::TextDomain(3) as specified in the section "SYNOPSIS", that means you have to **use** it, not **require** it. The module behaves quite differently compared to other modules.

Could you please tell me how one should detect if libintl-perl is present on target system, and how to provide dummy fallthrough implementation if it is not installed?  Or give examples of programs / modules which do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gettext manual is wrong to suggest that it is not okay for you to [demand a CPAN prerequisite](https://perldoc.perl.org/CPAN::Meta::Spec#prereqs). Everyone does this in the Perl world, and thanks to the CPAN infrastructure and toolchain, it works just fine. In the worst case you can bundle the dependencies you need.

The straight answer to your question is:

```
use Try::Tiny;
try {
    require Locale::TextDomain;
    Locale::TextDomain->import('my-package', @locale_dirs);
} catch {
    warn 'Soft dependency could not be loaded, using fallback.';
    require inc::Local::Dummy::Locale::TextDomain;
};
```

Explanation: [`use` is just `require` at compile time followed by `import`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html), and it is acceptable to split it in order to force this to execute at run time.

Answer (score 4):

You have to include Locale::TextDomain with use instead of require because it is intended for exactly this case, when you want unobtrusive i18n for Perl, when all it takes to internationalize your Perl code is to exchange that:

```
print "Hello world!\n";
```

with this:

```
use Locale::TextDomain qw (com.example.myapp);

print __"Hello world!\n";
```

In preprocessed languages like C this is easier to achieve.  About all internationalized C libraries contain a `#define` like this:

```
#define _(s) dgettext (GETTEXT_PACKAGE, s)
```

That means that `_("Hello world!\n")` expands to a function call that contains the textdomain of your package.  Perl sources cannot be portably preprocessed, and therefore `Locale::TextDomain` “abuses” the import mechanism of the use pragma for this purpose, so that it can associate a .pm file with a particular .mo file.  The textdomain is the filename stem of the .mo files your package installs.

If you don't like that approach, don't use it.  You can also make do without it:

```
require Locale::Messages;
print Locale::Messages::dgettext ("com.example.myapp", "Hello world!\n");
```

However, `Locale::TextDomain` is popular because it does the same in a much less obtrusive way.

About depending on a library that is non-core for Perl:

Whether a Perl module belongs to the Perl core or not depends on the Perl version.  And every user can install a different version of a Perl core module over the one that ships with her or his Perl.  Therefore, a robust package configuration will always check for the required version of a Perl library like it would check for the required version of any other library.  Assuming that checking for perl is the same as. checking for the presence of a particular version of a particular Perl module is a recipe for trouble.

BTW, `Try::Tiny` is also not part of the Perl core.  Maybe not the best choice using it for checking for the presence of other Perl modules.  When you want to test for libintl-perl, just execute `perl -MLocale::TextDomain -e exit` in your configure script and check the exit status.

Answer (score 2):

Based on daxim's answer, here's a possible implementation. It detects whether Locale::TextDomain is available, and provides simple no-op fallbacks for __ and __x functions. I'd appreciate improvements and suggestions for this code.

```
BEGIN
{
    if (eval("require Locale::TextDomain; 1;"))
    {
        Locale::TextDomain->import('my-package', @locale_dirs);
    }
    else
    {
        my $subCode = <<'EOF'

        sub __
        {
            return $_[0];
        }

        sub __x
        {
            my $s = shift;
            my %args = @_;
            $s =~ s/\{(\w+)\}/$args{$1}/sg;
            return $s;
        }
EOF
;
        eval($subCode);
    }
}
```

I think the whole code needs to live inside BEGIN, otherwise the __ and __x calls in your code cause errors. Also, the fallback functions are created with eval() to avoid "Prototype mismatch:" warnings. I'd be interested in a more elegant solution esp. for the latter point.

Comment: Perhaps **Package::Stash** or direct manipulation of symbol table instead of text eval.

Answer (score 1):

Create a directory "fallback/Locale" and create a module TextDomain.pm there with stub implementations for all functions that you need:

```
package Locale::TextDomain;

use strict;

sub __($) { return $_[0] }
sub __n($$$) { return $_[2] == 1 ? $_[0] : $_[1] }

# And so on, see the source of Locale::TextDomain for getting an
# idea how to implement the other stubs.
```

Now insert a BEGIN block into the entry point of your application (that is typically a .pl script, not a .pm module):

```
BEGIN {
    push @INC, "fallback";
}
```

Now Perl will **always** find Locale/TextDomain.pm in @INC, in doubt the stub implementation in the fallback directory.